# How to search items using multiple model fields

Tags: python, django

My search function currently looks like that:

```
query = request.GET.get('q')
if query:
    item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query) | item_list.filter(
        bike__brand__name__icontains=query) | item_list.filter(
        accessory__brand_accessory__name__icontains=query) | item_list.filter(
        bikepart__brand_part__name__icontains=query)
```

I can filter my items using single fields, but I am looking for a filter that can look up items using multiple fields.
My items are divided into 4 different models. `Item` model is a main model, that holds all titles for other models, that are connected to this main model, which are: `Bike`, `Accessory` and `BikePart`.

I am looking for filtering using `(title__icontains=query + bike__brand__name__icontains=query)`, `(title__icontains=query + accessory__brand_accessory__name__icontains=query)`, `(title__icontains=query + bikepart__brand_part__name__icontains=query)` , but I still wanna be able to look up items by using just a title or just brand. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Its good to use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in such complex cases

Comment: Have you tried filtering using `Q` ? Ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects